# Talking between different javascript windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have an asp.net web page that contains some javascript code and an Iframe element that views a different web page , my question is : are there any available ways to make these two windows communicate with each other ?

For eaxmple : I have a function called "Say HelloWorld" in the asp.net javascript code that should be invoked from the Iframe if a button in the Iframe page was clicked

Comment: If you can [control both pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), yes, otherwise no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it makes a huge difference if you are dealing with windows which access the same domain/port/protocol combination or not. In other words, does the Same Origin Policy bother you in any way. Regardless of SOP, you should read this: [HTML5 postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

If you are strictly dealing on the same domain, you don't really need magic like postMessage, but of course it wouldn't hurt you much either.

Comment: In this case , they will be hosted on the same domain , what should be done then ?

Comment: @AhmedKamal In that case, you can just access the `window` repectively `document` objects from each other. Either by accessing `parent` from the iFrame or `iframe.contentWindow` from the parent. There you have an option to access whatever JS related data.

Comment: I tried to do so but the frame web site has different port from the asp.net parent web app.

when I tried to access the parent from the child , I got this error

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63430" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: different port means, you're out of luck. Then, read the article about postMessage, SOP will not allow you any other.

Comment: Ok , Thanks a lot for your support , I have accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To Call parent from the child:

```
<script>
function calledFromChildIframe()  {
    alert("I am in Parent");
}
</script>

<iframe id="myFrame">
    ...........
    <a onclick="parent.calledFromChildIframe();" href="#" >Call Me </a>
</iframe>
```

Source: [**window.parent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent)

For the opposite case, 
assume your iFrame's id is "targetFrame" and the function you want to call is targetFunction()

```
document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetFunction();
```

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)